# Can I use GPL software to provide a commercial cloud service?

Tags: gpl, cloud

Rather than create my own software, can I just take existing GPL software and provide a cloud service around it? Will that be legal?

Comment: What makes you think you might not be able to do so? Please [edit] to explain.

Comment: My explanation...... me=noob =>

Comment: Maybe, he asked because he is scared of breaching copyright? Better ask first before having a problem later.

Comment: A *lot* of companies would go out of business if you couldn't.

Comment: There's a reason the LAMP stack took off.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can indeed. GPLv2 and GPLv3 only require that you distribute the source code when you're distributing the binaries. In the case of software-as-a-service you're not distributing binaries and, as such, you're under no obligation to distribute your source code either. This is sometimes referred to as the [SaaS loophole](https://resources.whitesourcesoftware.com/blog-whitesource/the-saas-loophole-in-gpl-open-source-licenses)

Comment: Thanks. Thats really bad for the developer! He did all the hard work and someone just swoop it away! Why would anyone want to GPL anyway then???

Comment: @user1034912 - I mean, I always do MIT license myself lol. Whereas GPL is (mostly) share and share alike MIT is not. But, speaking for myself, I'd rather people use my library and bolster my download count then open source any code that's using my library. To each their own!

Comment: @user1034912 because GPL was created before cloud was a thing. There is also AGPL

Comment: @user1034912:  The "swoop it away" is kind of the point of the GPL and other open sources licenses.  The author put the software under the GPL specifically to allow other people to use and modify it.  All of my personal projects are GPL.

Comment: @user1034912 I prefer MIT/BSD alikes either. What is the point of creating software for everyone and then release it under GPL license? You just seriosly limit your audience; most commercial (closed source) companies skip your code entirely due to the GPL. (License is first thing to look at while searching for reusable components - if it is GPL, then we just won't use it.) Development should be joy :)

Comment: @user253751 - GPLv3 came out in 2007. People were developing proprietary web apps before 2007. The term cloud may not have been as common place as it is now but hosting a proprietary web app on a physical machine isn't much different than hosting it "in the cloud", in so far as software licensing is concerned.

Comment: @user1034912, why would it be bad for the developer? They write the software to be used. If someone adds a value by providing all the computing resources to run it on, they can get paid for that and that's OK. I'd even say calling it a loophole is wrong, because it wasn't intended to be prohibited.

Comment: @JanHudec But they also write the software to be shared, and for modifications to be shared. If their main goal was usage, they'd use MIT. If their main goal was sharing, they'd use GPL. And we're talking about software that is GPL.

Comment: @user253751, the sharing mostly makes sense for those who can actually run the modified copy, which the end users may not be even on a shared local system like RMS had back then.

Comment: @JanHudec It's 2020. Everyone is running Linux on their servers. Everyone can run the modified copy.

Comment: I don't think the SaaS loophole has anything to do with it? If the software was AGPL the OP could still base a cloud service on it... they'd just have to release the source code if they made any changes.

Comment: @Arvo: Sure, that you don't use the Linux kernel, GCC compiler, bash shell interpreter and MariaDB, which are all GPL? Or is it just, that you don't include foreign code into your own projects, if that foreign code is GPL? But then, for code to be included, there is the LGPL.

Comment: I notice another protection from this is to use heavier server side codes, which works for OnPrem Installs, but not-optimized for SaaS deployments

Comment: Ok, but of OP ever starts shipping binaries, or merges/is acquired by a company that does or someday intends to, then tainting *is* an issue (or the overhead of policing separate codebases daily). Or, taking a penny of investment, or selling a share of equity, where any of the above common exit scenarios is a consideration. So, not necessarily today, but almost surely yes in the future. Unless OP always runs cash-positive.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, the GPL is a free software licence, and one of the properties of free (as in freedom) software is that you can use it for anything, including providing commercial online services.

This is not only legal; it is common. [Ángel](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/502/%c3%81ngel)’s answer provided some [good examples](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/11493/20983). A comment on the question mentioned the LAMP stack (half of which – Linux and MySQL – is GPL v2). Other examples are KVM, which is [licenced under GPL v2](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/virt/kvm/kvm.git/tree/COPYING), and OpenVZ (which is apparently GPL v2 as well, but it is split over many repositories so I have not verified this), both of which are used to provide VPS services.

There is one thing you should watch out for: the Free Software Foundation also released a licence called [AGPL (Affero General Public Licence)](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-affero-gpl.html), which is similar to the GPL. It adds a requirement to distribute (on request) source code to users who interact with the software over a network, even if those users never receive a copy of the object code. The AGPL addresses the concern you raised in [your comment](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/11467/can-i-take-a-gpl-product-and-make-a-commercial-cloud-service-from-it#comment28916_11468) on the other answer, about people locking up GPL’d software.

Comment: Personally, I think responses to comments should (mostly) be in the comments. If the OP edits their question only then should the answer be updated imho. I mean, comments can and often are deleted or moved to chat or whatever. If they are then half your answer ceases to have any context. It's just gratuitous information that's not related to the question at hand. And in any event, people shouldn't have to wade through a whole mess of comments to determine why a part of an answer is relevant. I mean, people are free to upvote what they will but I will not be copying your strategy!

Comment: @neubert (1/2) “Personally, I think responses to comments should (mostly) be in the comments.” This is not a “ response[] to comments”: the one time the answer mentions a comment, it does so merely to attribute an example that fits naturally into the answer. It would still make just as much sense if the comment was unavailable. “If the OP edits their question only then should the answer be updated imho.” What is so bad about editing answers?

Comment: @neubert (2/2) “It's just gratuitous information that's not related to the question at hand.” It is just as relevant as [Ángel’s answer] (which I upvoted, by the way), which has literally just three words that address the actual question. That answer has no comments and a positive score.

Answer (score 4):

There are three general flavours of the GPL around:

- The AGPL forces you to hand out source code to any user of your software upon request. For the AGPL, it doesn't matter, if the users downloaded the software as a binary to their machine or if they use it over a network on your server.
- The GPL requires you to hand out source code only, if you provided a binary. For software running on a server, you don't need to provide source code.
- The LGPL is the least restrictive: If you use LGPL code in a project, and distribute binaries, you only need to provide the source code of the LGPL parts, and the ability for the user to run the binary even after updating / upgrading the LGPL parts. This requirement is usually fulfilled by dynamically linking against LGPL libraries.

So, in your case, where you want to run a proprietary cloud service based on free software: Yes, you can do that with GPL software, but not with AGPL software.

Please keep in mind, that GPL and AGPL are *infectious*: If you have 500,000 lines of your own code and 5,000 lines of GPL code in a project, the whole joint work is still GPL. And if there are 1,000 more lines of AGPL in that project, it will even be AGPL.

LGPL on the contrary does not take over your code: You may link against LGPL libraries, most notable Linux/GNU libc, and don't loose any rights to your proprietary code.

Comment: -1 I upvoted this answer, but then realised that it does not actually answer the question.

Comment: regarding "infectious" licenses: GPL and AGPL are no different from any other software licenses: If you're given a possibility to use some code with a certain set of terms, then you must abide by any restrictions there are. Or not use the code at all. You can't expect to somehow get away by diluting the code into your own. After all, you wouldn't expect to be able to do that if you bought a commercial license for some (non-open) source code either?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out AGPL. Though as I read about this, it doesn't give the ultimate protection from SaaS-ing up a GPL. It just forces the SaaS-er to share his code (such as user/server management side of the code).

Comment: @ilkkachu Clearly, when the author said “infectious”, they meant “copyleft”. Their explanation was not the best, but that does not change the fact that GPL and AGPL *are* different from other licences.

Comment: @user1034912 What sort of “protection” are you looking for?

Comment: @ilkkachu I should have been more specific than “copyleft”. The FSF [uses the terms “strong copyleft” and “weak copyleft”](https://www.fsf.org/bulletin/2015/spring/demystifying-copyleft-1) to explain the difference between the (A)GPL and the LGPL.

Comment: @brian protection from oppprtunist saas'ers cause thats ultimately how i plan to monetize my open source app

Comment: More often, though, you will have 5,000 lines of your own and 500,000 provided by someone else.

Comment: @BrianDrake, "infectious" is a rather negative phrase. It's usually used in contexts like "infectious disease". Sounds a lot like FUD, actually. Again, GPL (all variants) are not that different from e.g. commercial licenses in that there's a set of conditions, which you need to follow, or you may end up in trouble. Of course they're a bit different compared to BSD/MIT-like "do what you like" licenses, since those don't really have too many conditions to follow in the first place.

Comment: -1 The term “proprietary … service” [is meaningless](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/network-services-arent-free-or-nonfree.html). The issues with the word “infectious”, discussed in the comments above, do not justify a downvote, but I suggest you change that word anyway.

Comment: About the term "infectious": There is a reason, why I use that term to describe GPL, and I have used it way before Covid came... The difference to other licenses: If you abuse a commercial license for your own project, and the person, whose software you abused, finds that out, they will sue you, probably for a lot of money. But if you abused some GPL code, you can also be sued to publish your code! And that's different to all commercial licenses.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. You can for instance provide a machine running a Linux kernel (GPLv2), with a web server using GnuTLS (LGPLv2.1+) and a web site built on Wordpress (GPLv2+).

From a business point of view, you should however take into account whether that is accessory or the main value of your service and which additional value you are providing.

For example, it would seem unlikely that a custom OS you coded from scratch performed better than using Linux (or other existing OS), and the actual OS is unlikely to matter for the service you will be providing.

On the other hand, if *everything* you provide is available by existing software (which is perfectly fine), you should mind which value you are providing versus your competition. Do you offer local support? Is it part of other services? Do you have a better expertise than other companies? (e.g. [Automattic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automattic) employing the main Wordpress developers) Are you much cheaper? Your business may flourish without any of them, but you may then rely on an higher demand than provided by the competitors which provide more value (however that is perceived by your clients) than you.

Although more noticeable when using FOSS, note these are things you must mind as well even if everything you offered was your own proprietary code. You may have built an acceptable blog software, but a competitor using Wordpress (and thus with less investing) might be providing a service as good or better than yours.