# Using Modified Linux in an Embedded device, the source code must be opened?

Tags: gpl

In Brazil Elections, they developed a modified Linux version called "UENUX" to run 570 thousand electronic vote machines, where the people go to Vote on those machines.

Since they really mixed their code with a modified Linux distribution, I presume all code is "automatically" GPL-2.0. In this case, it's mandatory to open/release the code because people are using it in the voting machine? Thanks.

(as a general question: "people that Just Use a product whose software runs under a GPL license, can require access to the source code?")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No: the GPL triggers on *distribution*, not on use. The owners of the voting machines are the ones who the binaries have been distributed to so they can request the source code, but the end users cannot.

This is essentially the same as the [SaaS loophole](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/11467/can-i-use-gpl-software-to-provide-a-commercial-cloud-service).

Comment: And the entire distro isn't likely to be GPL, anyway.  The kernel certainly is, and other software may well be, but some will be under permissive free licences.

Comment: Good point; I may have interpreted "a modified Linux version" a bit literally.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This is another topic, but when you said "The owners of the voting machines", make me think, those who paid it are the people, the real owners.

Comment: @John That's not an argument which would hold any water at all in most Western countries; "the people" do not own everything their taxes have paid for ("yes, I'll just take this tank, thank you General"). I have no specifics about Brazilian law but I would be incredibly surprised if you get anywhere with it - but ask on Law SE if you really want to.

Comment: @John This is what the Free Software Foundation is trying to achieve with their [Public money? Public code!](https://publiccode.eu) campaign.

Comment: I wonder if at least they need to inform the Authors/Contributors' names. I guess even in the BSD license is "required authors of all works deriving from a BSD-licensed work to include an Acknowledgment of the Original Source in All advertising material".

Comment: Only in the original 4 clause BSD license. The advertising requirement is dropped in the 2/3 clause versions for various reasons, including being incompatible with the GPL.

Comment: @John, well, the taxpayers as a group can exercise their rights of ownership by voting in people who agree to their goals. Or that's how it's supposed to work in a representative democracy anyway. A single taxpayer would individually only "own" a tiny part of the voting machines anyway. (Of course with the GPL, the source code to the distributed programs must be released for even person who cares to ask. But the voting machines' software isn't distributed to the taxpayers.)